# Does it exists probability space $\Omega = (N, \mathcal{P}(A), P)$ that $P({n}) = const$ for $n \in N$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm started my probability course two weeks ago and misunderstand how to approach
to the following problem

Does it exists probability space $\Omega = (\mathbb N, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N), P)$ that $P(\{n\}) = const$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ ?

M b I can not understand the essence of this task.

But how should I start?

I have two ideas.

The first one is:
if $P(${$n$}$) = const$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sum P(${$n$}$) = 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $const \rightarrow 0$ and we have contradiction.

And the second one:
Assume that if $n$ is even $P(${$N$}$) = 0.5$, if uneven $P(${$N$}$) = 0.5$

Thank u

Comment: Is $N$ shorthand for $\{1, \ldots, N\}$? If so, the uniform distribution would satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Your first idea works.  I don't understand your second idea.

Comment: If $N$ is shorthand for all the natural numbers, then no - there is no uniform distribution on the natural numbers

Comment: $\mathcal{N}$ is the infinite set of Natural numbers